# How to request the user to access the storage of phone?

Tags: flutter, flutter-image-picker

[image]

I try to code some gallery picker function from Youtube but I want to ask for permission for storage to user ,when I code below code, I get into the app info why I get there and how to fix it

```
import 'package:photo_manager/photo_manager.dart';

class MediaServices {
  Future loadAlbum(RequestType requestType) async {
    var permission = await PhotoManager.requestPermissionExtend();
    List<AssetPathEntity> albumList = [];
    if (permission == true) {
      albumList = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(
        type: requestType,
      );
    } else {
      PhotoManager.openSetting();
    }
    return albumList;
  }
  Future loadAssets(AssetPathEntity selectedAlbum) async {
  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  List<AssetEntity> assetList = await selectedAlbum.getAssetListRange(
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      start: 0, end: selectedAlbum.assetCount);
      return assetList;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Permission handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin from pub.dev, this is similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71993943/14360762)

**for android add these lines in Androidmainfest.xml file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**for iOS add below code in info.plist file**

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app require permission to access microphone</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app require permission to access gallery</string>
```

**modify below code accordingly.**

```
 Future<void> getStorageReadPermission() async {
    final storage = await Permission.storage.status;
    !storage.isGranted
        ? await Permission.storage.request()
        : debugPrint("Storage read permission already granted");
  }

  Future<void> getStorageManagePermission() async {
    final manageStorage = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
    !manageStorage.isGranted
        ? await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request()
        : debugPrint("storage permission already granted");
  }
```

Comment: Why are you asking for Microphone access? It has nothing to do with storage.

Comment: asking for Microphone access is for Apple, because you will be using the Camera @Canilho

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out that I have missed something in my code . And I watched video agian and I realized it.I have to put "if(permission.isAuth==true)" instead of this one "if(permission==true)".

**Instead of this**

```
import 'package:photo_manager/photo_manager.dart';

class MediaServices {
  Future loadAlbum(RequestType requestType) async {
    var permission = await PhotoManager.requestPermissionExtend();
    List<AssetPathEntity> albumList = [];
    if (permission == true) {
      albumList = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(
        type: requestType,
      );
    } else {
      PhotoManager.openSetting();
    }
    return albumList;
  }
  Future loadAssets(AssetPathEntity selectedAlbum) async {
  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  List<AssetEntity> assetList = await selectedAlbum.getAssetListRange(
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      start: 0, end: selectedAlbum.assetCount);
      return assetList;
}
```

**I have to use this one**

```
import 'package:photo_manager/photo_manager.dart';

class MediaServices {
  Future loadAlbum(RequestType requestType) async {
    var permission = await PhotoManager.requestPermissionExtend();
    List<AssetPathEntity> albumList = [];
    if (permission.isAuth == true) {
      albumList = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(
        type: requestType,
      );
    } else {
      PhotoManager.openSetting();
    }
    return albumList;
  }
  Future loadAssets(AssetPathEntity selectedAlbum) async {
  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  List<AssetEntity> assetList = await selectedAlbum.getAssetListRange(
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      start: 0, end: selectedAlbum.assetCount);
      return assetList;
}
```